# How to find number of cluster in spectral Clustering in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I have 4831*7 shape of matrix now I want to perform spectral clustering. So how can I choose the number of clusters?

Comment: You need to pass the number of clusters in to the algorithm. Are you asking how you should choose the number of clusters?

Comment: yes, how you should choose the number of clusters?

Comment: This depends on your specific problem - the shape of the matrix certainly isn't enough information to make an informed decision with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different approaches like [silhouette score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html) or [mutual information](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score.html).